# Adding multiple numbers together from a list box c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sum, do-loops

Im trying to add numbers together inside a list box. First of all i put the numbers inside the listbox into an array and integers.

I now want to sum all the numbers together inside the list_box to give me a total.

The way i was going to approach this was in a loop and add each number incrementally.

Any help would be very much appreciated, as im really struggling after just starting my HND so im at a  extremly very basic level with only covering some basic methods.

```
    private void rb_sum_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //array is needed here at this point
        string boxnumbers = list_box.Text;
        int[] boxnumbers1 = new int[10];

        int answer;

        do
        {
            boxnumbers1 += add.answer();
        }

        while ();
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing with that code?

Comment: Can you clarify why boxnumbers is even there and why you're attempted to add to an array using an unknown variable add with a method answer().  Also what is the value of list_box.Text

Answer (score 2):

The magic of LINQ will save you, try **.Sum()**

Your code doesn't make much sense so I'll try to clear it up. 
I assume you have several rows of numbers in the list box like this.

```
1
5
3
6
```

Assuming you loaded it correctly as a list of ints, you get an sum of them using the following:

```
int sum = list_box.Items.Sum(i => (int)i.Value);
```

If you loaded it incorrectly as strings, then you need to parse it:

```
int sum = list_box.Items.Sum(i => int.Parse(i.Value));
```

You need to clarify your question a bit more if this doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

A for loop might be better for you:

```
for(var i = 0; i < boxnumbers1.Count; i++)
{
     answer += boxnumbers1[i];
}
```